# react native sentry doest not send crash reports under NavigationContainer

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, sentry

we have self hosted sentry server (Sentry 21.11.0 172bad1), our react native SDK is : "@sentry/react-native": "^3.0.2"

sentry can detect all crashes all over the app ( because events logs are available in beforeSend function )
but only crashes in those components that registered before react navigation NavigationContainer , report crashes on sentry panel,
and crashed accrued in react navigation screens are not reported
PS : enabling navigation integration does not help

PS1: our init funtion is  :

```
export const initCrashReportServices = () => {
  const information = {
    dsn: 'XXXX',
    debug: ENVIRONMENT === 'STG',
    environment: ENVIRONMENT,
    attachStacktrace: true,
    beforeSend: async event => {
      console.log(event, 'event');
      return event;
    },
  };
  codePush
    .getUpdateMetadata()
    .then(update => {
      alert(`${update.appVersion}+codepush:${update.label}`);
      if (update) {
        information.release = `${update.appVersion}+codepush:${update.label}`;
      }
      Sentry.init(information);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      Sentry.init(information);
    });
};
```

PS2:
App.js :

```
export default codePush({
  checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_RESUME,
})(
  Sentry.withErrorBoundary(App, { fallback: ErrorBoundaryComponent }),
);
```